# Need in understanding classpath in resource location and variable value set

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, classpath

Although I have been working in java for a while, there are many small things I have been ignoring, which at times have become bottleneck in productivity. I have difficulty in understanding this:

This is one of the bean.xml which gets placed in the final .war file (in a web application, built with spring framework).

```
<context:property-placeholder 
    location="classpath:/${deploy.env}/com.example.config/db.properties"
    ignore-resource-not-found="false" />
```

I have following doubts:

1) At the time of building the code, i did like this for passing value of deploy.env

```
mvn clean install -Ddeploy.env=local
```

I ran the mvn in debug mode and could see this set to local. Now, the thing is, in the .war that gets generated, it is still ${deploy.env} (see above snippet). Doesn't this get replaced in the final .war? If not, then how do we pass the value which we intend to set?

2) what does `"classpath:/${deploy.env}/com.example.config/db.properties"` mean? Who sets the value of classpath? Are classpath capable of providing the location of resource files as well?

Assuming deploy.set --> local, so would this get translated to:

```
classpath:"/local/com.example.config/db.properties"
```

So does this mean db.properties would be present at: `/local/com.example.config/db.properties`

Any inputs to understand this would be of great help.

Comment: I'd replace the tags you've got with "Maven"

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion,done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deploy.env` is either environment variable or system property available to the JVM at run time.

The `classpath:/${deploy.env}/com.example.config/db.properties` will be resolved at run when your war is running in the container.

Set `deploy.env=whatever` in the shell from where you starting the tomcat or set in the environment of the user which starts the tomcat.

`mvn clean install -Ddeploy.env=local` here the deploy.env system property is available at build time. This will not replace the value of your spring config.

`classpath` is where all your classes and libraries bundled in the war are available along with the tomcat libraries. The spring property configurer will look for the `db.properties` file in the classpath at location e.g. `/local/com.example.config`

[Spring documentation to learn more](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources)
[Some explanation on my blog post](http://tothepointtalks.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/spring-externalize-application.html)

Comment: I have deployed this application in tomcat. So does this need to be provided by tomcat?

Comment: yes but you would need to pass the value, see updated answer

Comment: So would it look for file at "absolute" path or the path appended to classpath?  That is path --> /local/com.example.config/ or this path relative to the classpath path's?

Comment: I think your path is wrong. If you show the path of db.properties in your war then I can help. In my war if db.properties is in `classes\com\example\config` folder then it should be `classpath:com\example\config\db.properties`. What you want to achieve with `deploy.env`?

Comment: Thanks so much for your valuable inputs. I was asking  if classpath:/${deploy.env}/com.example.config/db.properties means to find the db.properties with respect to the paths in classpath? For example, if classpath has value: /opt and /home,then  would these be the locations at which file would be tried to be found: /opt/${deploy.env}/com.example.config/db.properties AND /home/${deploy.env}/com.example.config/db.properties?

Comment: If classpath has value `/opt` then you should not have `/opt` in your `classapth:/opt/${deploy.env}/com.example.config/db.properties`. Also by the look of this you should be using `file:` and not `classpath:`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your info, do you have any pointer to material which I can refer to?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the Oracle Web site: The `CLASSPATH` variable is one way to tell applications, including the JDK tools, where to look for user classes.

That `classpath:` is referring to that location in particular, whatever it is, so it will start looking for those resources defined by Spring from that location and on, until it finds the first match.

Also, if you have that as a property in Maven, the value can be replaced with the right plug-in and configuration; not quite useful when you want a build that can be used with many values within those `.properties` files for different environments.

You can use other prefixes as `file:`, `http:`, etcetera. But you are just wondering about `classpath:`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I am more curious to classpath, as I am under the impression that classpath is used to locate .class files only.

Comment: Not in that case. It's just the location from where to start looking for whatever you define as a "resource" in your Spring configuration